# Is it possible to use Tango fisheye camera and rgb sensor at the same time?

Tags: google-project-tango, fisheye

As far as I researched, it seems that it is not possible to use the Tango fisheye camera and the rgb sensor at the same time.

Thus is it possible to take a color picture with the fisheye camera on Tango?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possibile to take color picture with the fisheye simply because RGB camera and fisheye camera are two different hw devices as you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/tango/hardware/tablet#get_started_learning_about_tango)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, is it possible to get a colored picture taken by the fisheye camera instead of a black-and-white one?

Comment: I think fisheye camera of the Tango Dev Kit is only back-and-white, so I think it is not possibile.